# Cannot find type 'WKMediaCaptureType' in scope Swift compiler error in Ionic for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

when I tried to compile my Ionic app to iOs using ionic cap build ios and when I try to run I have some errors.

Swift compiler error

1- Cannot find type 'WKMediaCaptureType' in scope
2- Cannot find type 'WKPermissionDecision' in scope

The app is complete in blank, just to test the ios app. I'm using the demo tab app that ionic give to you.

My english is not very well, but can you please help me to fix this issue?

this is the error that I have from XCODE

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Xcode 13 to compile capacitor 4 apps

Comment: Thanks, I will update my xcode and try it again.